# How to use an activity indicator for web service login

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityindicatorview

I just created an iOS app which uses web service and my problem here is when I tap log in the view controller is idle not displaying the activity indicator but when the response and data from web service is fetched and the next view controller is loaded; the activity indicator quickly appears. I want the activity indicator visible at the time when I tap the log in button

---

Code sample:

```
NSString *username = TextUsername.text; 
NSString *password = Textpassword.text; 
NSString *strLogInUrl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@""]; 
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES]; 
NSLog(@"Url %@",strLogInUrl); 
NSURL *URLGet = [NSURL URLWithString:strLogInUrl]; 
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URLGet]; 
NSError* error; 
DicForAllData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

Comment: which method are you using for web service are you using AFNetworking ?

Comment: Please provide some code. Thnx.

Comment: No am not using AFNetworking @UnicoRahul

Comment: NSString *username = TextUsername.text;
   NSString *password = Textpassword.text;    NSString *strLogInUrl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@""];
       [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
    NSLog(@"Url %@",strLogInUrl);
    NSURL *URLGet= [NSURL URLWithString:strLogInUrl];
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URLGet];
        NSError* error;
        DicForAllData = [NSJSONSerialization
                         JSONObjectWithData: data
                         options:kNilOptions
                         error:&error];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're using synchronous code to log in. If you do something like this:

```
display activity indicator
log in (synchronously)
hide activity indicator
```

Then the activity indicator never gets a chance to display. (UI changes don't get rendered to the screen until after your code returns and the app visits the event loop.)

You should either change your login code to work asynchronously (best option) or rewrite your code to visit the event loop between displaying the activity indicator and logging in. Pseudocode might look like this:

```
display activity indicator
[self performSelector: @selector(login) withObject: nil afterDelay: 0];
```

And your login method pseudocode:

```
- (void) login;
{
  log in (synchronously)
  hide activity indicator
}
```

(`performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` does not execute the code from the selector right away. Instead, it queues up a call to your selector for the next time the app visits the event loop. Your code gets called after the system has a chance to update the screen {specifically, after it gets a chance to display your activity indicator}.)

Comment: He definitely should be logging in asynchronously! I know you know this, but OP should know that performing synchronous network calls entails lots of other problems. He should never perform synchronous network requests from main thread.

Comment: That sort of depends on app design. Login is a special case where a synchronous call might not be so bad. If the app needs to stop everything and not allow any other user interaction until the login is complete then making it synchronous is reasonable. If you want **ANY* user interaction to be possible (including a login cancel button) then you must use an async call for login.

Comment: But if you hit home button and then pop back to the app, watchdog process comes into play and will summarily kill your app if network request doesn't finish in a timely manner. I agree that you functionally may want the app to not accept user input during a login process, but synchronous request is invariably the wrong way to achieve that.

Comment: how to make the code to work asynchronus please provide me a sample am trying  with this [self performSelector: @selector(login) withObject: nil afterDelay: 0]; as you have described

Comment: There is no single answer to how to make your login code asynchronous. Take a look at NSURLConnection. It has both a class method, `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:', and an init method for async use: `initWithRequest:delegate:`. You'll need to update your question with info about your login code before we can give you more help than that.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, to let the UI update, you want to perform this asynchronously. Before I drag you through the weeds on some details, let's consider a high-level abstraction of the code in your question:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URLGet]; 
// do something with data
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
```

Instead of that synchronous request, you really want to issue an asynchronous request like so:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = ...;
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
    // handle the data or connectionError here, inside this block, and remember to turn off activity indicator
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
}];
```

---

The thing is, your code snippet is not creating the request properly. You've over-simplified the process. Your process should really also consider:

1. If you're supplying credentials, that's invariably a `POST` request, not a simple `GET` that `dataWithContentsOfURL` performs.
2. You really should probably construct a proper `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request.
3. You have to percent escape the data being passed to the server (without that, if the password happened to contain certain reserved characters, such as `+` or `&`, the login would fail).
4. You really should be handling errors.

Pulling all of that together, it looks more like:

```
// tell the user we're going to do this request for them
// maybe show a `UIActivityIndicatorView`, too

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];

// construct the body of the request; replace the keys `username` and `password` with whatever your web service requires

NSString *username = textUsername.text;
NSString *password = textPassword.text;
NSString *parameterString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@", [self percentEscapeString:username], [self percentEscapeString:password]];
NSData *httpBody = [parameterString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

// now create the request itself

NSString *strLogInUrl = @"http://example.com";
NSURL *URLGet = [NSURL URLWithString:strLogInUrl];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URLGet];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:httpBody];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

// now send the request

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
    if (!data) {
        NSLog(@"connectionError: %@", connectionError);
    } else {
        NSError* error;
        dicForAllData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

        // do what you want with the data/error here, e.g. `[self.tableView reloadData]` or whatever
    }

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
}];
```

And that assumes that you have a percent escaping routine, something like:

```
- (NSString *)percentEscapeString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *result = CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                                                 (CFStringRef)string,
                                                                                 (CFStringRef)@" ",
                                                                                 (CFStringRef)@":/?@!$&'()*+,;=",
                                                                                 kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
    return [result stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
}
```

---

Earlier, UnicoRahul inquired whether you were using AFNetworking. It's worth considering as it greatly simplifies the code you have to write:

```
NSDictionary *params = @{@"username": username, @"password": password};
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

[manager POST:@"http://example.com" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    dicForAllData = responseObject;

    // do what you want with the data here, e.g. `[self.tableView reloadData]` or whatever
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you tap on login button, before calling web service call activity indicator and after a second call web service so, the activity indicator will be shown/displayed. Once you get the response first stop the activity indicator and then push to next view controller.

Remember before pushing to next screen make the keyboard dismiss. it's a good practice.

Comment: yeah i tried with this but it does not work the UI does not display the activity indicater untill the data from web service is loaded

Comment: - (IBAction)ButtonLogin:(id)sender
{
Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
NetworkStatus internetStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
[reachability startNotifier];

Comment: if (internetStatus == NotReachable)
 {
   UIAlertView* alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"ERROR !!!!!!"
                                                      message:@"Failed to connect to Internet" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];

Comment: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
        [alert show];
    }
    else
    {
        if (checkboximage1.hidden == YES)
        {       
          NSLog(@"Unchecked");  
        }

Comment: else if (checkboximage1.hidden == NO)
        {
            NSLog(@"checked");
            NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

Comment: [defaults setObject:TextUsername.text  forKey:@"Username"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
        }

Comment: NSString *username = TextUsername.text;
   NSString *password = Textpassword.text;
    NSString *strLogInUrl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"example.com/mobile/login?userName=%@&password=%@",username,password];

Comment: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
   NSLog(@"Url %@",strLogInUrl);
    NSURL *URLGet= [NSURL URLWithString:strLogInUrl];
    @try
    {
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URLGet];
        NSError* error;

Comment: DicForAllData = [NSJSONSerialization
                         JSONObjectWithData: data
                         options:kNilOptions
                         error:&error];
        
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception)
    {
        NSLog(@"Exception %@",exception);
    }
    NSString *str= [DicForAllData valueForKey:@"id"];
    NSUserDefaults *newRequestDetails=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

Comment: [newRequestDetails setObject:str forKey:@"LogInId"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
    
    NSString *str_LogInId=[newRequestDetails valueForKey:@"LogInId"];
    
    NSLog(@"Main Log in ID %@",str_LogInId);
    
    if (str)
    {
        NSLog(@"Y%@",DicForAllData);
        [self.view endEditing:YES];
       
       if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
        {
        EMR_Home *EMR_HomeVC = [[EMR_Home alloc] initWithNibName:@"EMR-Home~Ipad" bundle:nil];

Comment: [[self navigationController] pushViewController:EMR_HomeVC animated:YES];
        }
        else
        {
         EMR_Home *EMR_HomeVC = [[EMR_Home alloc] initWithNibName:@"EMR-Home~Iphone" bundle:nil];

Comment: @Jayasabeen In the future, please edit your question, add your code snippet there, rather than putting it in comments like that.